# SNAPD automatic updates and sunning servers in LXC

Tags: snap, lxc

Recently Ubuntu moved LXC into snaps which raises a concern with snapd updates. Those updates can not be configured to be manual, they run on schedule and can't be turned off. As I am thinking to have a NAS and a VPN servers running in LXC containers but I am concerned whether snapd updates will be shutting down or restarting those containers and therefore causing potential data loss with NAS or security issues with VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can defer any package updates up to sixty days.
By doing so, you have a window of two months to select when you can perform the update.

Not updating a package is a security issue by itself.